# Mongoose not returning data for second collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a serverless application that is not returning any values for one of my collections.

My function queries Mongo for 3 collections.

even though the locationTypes collect contains 5 documents, none are returned. Location & Failure collections do return data.

```
const Location = require('./models/Location');
const LocationType = require('./models/LocationType');
var locationPromise = Location.find();
var locationTypePromise = LocationType.find();
var failurePromise = Failure.find();

Promise.all([locationPromise, locationTypePromise, failurePromise])
    .then(values => res.json({ locations: values[0], locationTypes: values[1], failures: values[2] }))
```

models/Location.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const LocationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  Description: String,
  Type: String,
  Parent: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Location', LocationSchema);
```

models/LocationType.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const LocationTypeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  Description: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('LocationType', LocationTypeSchema);
```

Could the problem be related to the collection having a compound name?

Comment: Above your code, you say "locationTypes" (lowercase L, plural) but in your code you have "LocationType" (uppercase L, singluar). Which is it?

Comment: Collection is called locationTypes. It's my understanding that mongoose hands the pluralarity. it definitely does for the locations collection.

Comment: how do you enter data in Location collection? thru cli or native mongo driver?

Comment: if you have entered records in Location collection thru CLI or native mongo driver try to add {collection: "collection_name"} in LocationSchema

Comment: In the model for LocationType, the following works:
const LocationTypeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  Description: String
}, { collection: "locationTypes" });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem comes from how Mongoose interprets model names. When you give Mongoose a model name, it automatically pluralizes it to find the relevant MongoDB collection name. Simple words such as `location` are easily pluralized to `locations`, but a compound name such as `locationType` can't be pluralized to `locationTypes` without extra information.

```
const LocationTypeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ Description: String }, { collection: "locationTypes" });
```

Adding `{ collection: "locationTypes" }` tells Mongoose that the `LocationType` schema should be mapped to the `locationTypes` collection.

See Mongoose's [official documentation on this](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#collection).